# After updating google play services wearable app is not connected to mobile app

Tags: android

I used GPS version 8.1.0. But when I update Google PS version to 8.3.0, my application is not worked. Why?
Maybe, my gradle files is not correctly..
It's my gradle file of wear app.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.unated"
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 15
    versionName "1.3.2.0.0"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}



buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}
ext {
GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION = '8.3.0'
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:1.0+'
stagingCompile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:$GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION"
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'
compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.14.2'
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.smoothprogressbar:library:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

My mobile app gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'testfairy'

ext {
APPLICATION_ID = "com.unated"
COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 23
MIN_SDK_VERSION = 14
TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 21
}

android {
compileSdkVersion COMPILE_SDK_VERSION
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId APPLICATION_ID
    minSdkVersion MIN_SDK_VERSION
    targetSdkVersion TARGET_SDK_VERSION
    versionCode 15
    versionName "1.3.2.0.0"
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}



lintOptions {
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
    abortOnError false
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

ext {
GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION = '8.3.0'
daggerVersion = '2.0.1'
SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '23.1.1'
LOMBOK_VERSION = '1.14.2'
}

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/intercom/intercom-maven' }
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
wearApp project(':wear')
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile project(':recyclerviewfastscroller')
compile project(':vksdk_library')

provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:$LOMBOK_VERSION" // getters setters boilerplate
apt "org.projectlombok:lombok:$LOMBOK_VERSION"


compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:$GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:$GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:$GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION"
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.smoothprogressbar:library:1.0.0'
compile 'com.f2prateek.dart:dart:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.8.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:+'
}

apt {
arguments {
    resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId
    androidManifestFile   variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting can u share your error log ?

Comment: Nothing errors.Data from mobile app is reach to wear app after same time (5-10 minutes). When gps version was 8.1, time was some seconds